# How to escape quotes in search to ContentProvider?

Tags: android

How to escape quotes in search to ContentProvider?
Query like this:

```
String value = "O'Key" ;/ / string contains a quote

Cursor people = cr.query (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String [] {Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + "= '" + value + "'", null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + "ASC ");
```

Such a request generates an error because the quotes in the string is interpreted as the end of the line. Need to escape the character, but \ '- it does not work here!
Sorry for bad English.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: http://blog.srijna.com/2010/11/08/how-to-escape-single-quotes-while-using-sqlitedatabasecontent-providers-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
String value = "O'Key" ;/ / string contains a quote

Cursor people = cr.query (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    new String [] {Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER},
    Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?",
    new String[] {value},
    Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + "ASC ");
```

Comment: Thank you, Henry! You've been very helpful.